# Efficiently convert from Shapefile to GeoJSON without GDAL

Tags: shapefile, geojson, convert, software-recommendations, command-line

Ogr2ogr is the standard way to convert files from Shapefile to GeoJSON on the command line. But it has a few limitations for me:

- The output format is not condensed (ie, it contains a lot of needless whitespace, which adds up for huge files)
- There doesn't seem to be an option to suppress null values (again, very inefficient on space)
- GDAL is an enormous package that does a lot of stuff I don't need (so it's a very heavy dependency for this one tiny job).

Is there any better tool for the job?

Comment: GeoTools can do it in Java but it is not small either. OpenJUMP has native drivers for both formats but it is probably difficult to run without using the UI. I guess that both will create uncondensed result with nulls.

Answer (score 5):

Pyshp reads and writes shapefiles, no other formats, in Python: `pip install pyshp`.

You can use its Python [geo protocol](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp#python-geo-interface) to get GeoJSON-like representations of features and then use Python's json module to serialize them to JSON. See https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html for examples of compact encoding.

Mike Bostock's https://www.npmjs.com/package/shapefile also does command line conversion of shapefiles.

Comment: Well, ogr2ogr is *one* way to do it. I believe that the CLI in my Fiona package is more standard in that it supports GeoJSON text sequences and interacts better with stdin and stdout: https://github.com/sgillies/frs-cheat-sheet#convert-vectors-to-geojson. Also requires GDAL, however.

Comment: Thank you - that led to some other useful links like https://github.com/gipong/shp2geojson.js and https://github.com/wavded/js-shapefile-to-geojson